How to Sum up / Total MRVS Data - ServiceNow Catalog Item
How to Sum up / Total MRVS Data - ServiceNow - Catalog Item


Steps to Follow:

Create a new variable Custom in the catalog item.
Inside the Type Specification column, select the widget (Create a new widget and replace the below client script)

Note: Make sure to update the variable name correctly as explained in the comments.


api.controller = function($scope, $rootScope) {
    var c = this;
    
    $rootScope.$on("field.change", function(evt, parms) {
        
        var g_form = $scope.page.g_form;
        
        if (parms.field.name == "course_data") { // Replace "course_data" with the your MVRS internal name
            
            if (g_form.getValue('course_data')) { //Replace "course_data" with the your MVRS internal name
                
                var rows = JSON.parse(g_form.getValue('course_data')); //Replace "course_data" with the your MVRS internal name
                console.log(rows);
                
                var sum_course_fees = 0;
                var sum_other_fees = 0;
                
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (rows[i].course_fees) { //Replace "course_fees" with the your MVRS -> Variable name
                        sum_course_fees += parseInt(rows[i].course_fees);  //Replace "course_fees" with the your MVRS -> Variable name
                    }
                    if (rows[i].other_fees) { //Replace "other_fees" with the your MVRS -> Variable name
                        sum_other_fees += parseInt(rows[i].other_fees); //Replace "other_fees" with the your MVRS -> Variable name
                    }
                    
                }
                
                // Update the "total_sum_course_fees" and "total_sum_other_fees" fields with the your variable name
                g_form.setValue('total_sum_course_fees', parseInt(sum_course_fees));
                g_form.setValue('total_sum_other_fees', parseInt(sum_other_fees));
                
            }else{
                
                // Update the "total_sum_course_fees" and "total_sum_other_fees" fields with the your variable name
                g_form.setValue('total_sum_course_fees', '');
                g_form.setValue('total_sum_other_fees', '');
            }
        }
    });
};



